# working with unintialized variables in C#

Tags: c#, variables

this is probably quite a simple problem, however, I can't figure out how to get around this. Basically, my class Client requires a work address value, however, it's not 100% required when creating a client. In creating the variable to be used for the object creation i'm using a string value which will then get the value from a text box. I am then checking to see if the textbox is empty, if it is, the string value of the variable is just a whitespace. Else, it's the textbox value.

```
string homeAdd;
if(homeAddressText.Text == String.Empty)
{
    homeAdd = " ";
}
else if (homeAddressText.Text != String.Empty)
{
    homeAdd = homeAddressText.Text;
}
```

As seen here..

However, when I go to create the client object using this variable, I get an error saying 'use of unassigned local variable 'homeAdd'.

```
Client client = new Client(firstN, lastN, homeAdd, workAdd, email, homeP, cellP);
```

Is there a simple way I can do the checking I require and still use the variable?

Thanks in advance guys/gals.

Comment: Your code MAY leave homeAdd uninitialized. So, your compiler responds an error 'use of unassigned local variable'. Change your else if to else or just start your code by initializing homeAdd with a value and change it if !string.IsNullOrEmpty(homeAddressText.Text).

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen: That depends on whether `homeAddressText.Text` could change between the two calls :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the whole `else if` line to just:

```
else
```

The two conditions are exact opposites.  Your code would work (but is verbose) in theory, provided the textbox is only touched on the UI thread.  However, the compiler can not confirm this.

Comment: Actually, what the compiler does it quite smart: It takes into consideration that `homeAddressText.Text` might have been changed by another thread between the two checks.

Comment: Actually, if the app is multi-threaded (and the compiler has to assume it may be), the value of `homeAddressText.Text` could change between the two if statements.

Comment: @dtb, Jeffrey, if the compiler were smarter, it would realize that only the UI thread should be touching the GUI. ;)  Point taken, though.

Comment: @Jeffrey, Jon [demonstrated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925803/working-with-unintialized-variables-in-c-sharp/7926038#7926038) that the compiler doesn't figure it out even when threading is not a factor.  It's true that the condition is redundant, though.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you should do in this situation is work out *why* the compiler is complaining. Clearly it thinks there's some way of executing *neither* of those assignments. Now *sometimes* this is because the compiler is "dumb" (or rather, because the language design isn't powerful enough to notice when you've covered all possible cases). However, usually it's because you've overlooked something, or made an assumption which the compiler isn't willing to make.

You've made the assumption that the value of `homeAddressText.Text` will remain the same between two calls (which isn't necessarily valid) *and* that `!=` and `==` will give reverse answers when given the same operands (which is a more reasonable assumption, but one the compiler wouldn't make). In fact, the compiler isn't even *trying* to be smart here - it only considers each condition separately, so even this doesn't compile:

```
// Local variable - can't possibly change...
int x = ...;
int y;
if (x == 5)
{
    y = 1;
}
else if (x != 5) // The compiler *could* realize this is the inverse...
{
    y = 2;
}
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Ultimately, it's not worth the language becoming more complicated to let you write redundant code - it's *better* to force you to remove the redundancy.

So, how can we avoid this? How can we make it clear to the compiler and any future readers that we'll definitely be taking one course or another? We can simply remove the condition of the second option:

```
if (homeAddressText.Text == String.Empty)
{
    homeAdd = " ";
}
else
{
    homeAdd = homeAddressText.Text;
}
```

Now we will obviously take the first branch *or* the second, as that's the whole point of an `else` block. However, now we've got a pattern of:

```
if (condition)
{
    variable = expression1;
}
else
{
    variable = expression2;
}
```

and *personally* I like to use the conditional operator in such situations - it makes the whole aim of "I want to assign a value to the variable, based on a condition" more explicit:

```
variable = condition ? expression1 : expression2;
```

So in this case, it would leave your code as:

```
homeAdd = homeAddressText.Text == String.Empty ? " " : homeAddressText.Text;
```

Now that's possibly where I'd leave it - but it would be *nice* if we could only mention `homeAddressText.Text` *once*. If you find yourself doing this regularly, you might want to consider writing an extension method:

```
public static string DefaultIfNullOrEmpty(this string input, string defaultValue)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? defaultValue : input;
}
```

Then your assignment becomes:

```
homeAdd = homeAddress.Text.DefaultIfNullOrEmpty(" ");
```

That's very explicit about the situations in which the default is used (for example, it *doesn't* default if you've just got whitespace) but if brevity is more important to you, you could rename it:

```
homeAdd = homeAddress.Text.OrDefault(" ");
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the work if I understood your problem correctly.

```
string homeAdd = " "; //initialize to the default value
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(homeAddressText.Text))
{
   homeAdd = homeAddressText.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change to:

```
string homeAdd;
if(homeAddressText.Text == String.Empty)
{
    homeAdd = " ";
}
else
{
    homeAdd = homeAddressText.Text;
}
```

You don't need the second if as you know it is true if it gets there.
The compiler is smart enough to know that the variable would be initialized if it's assigned to in each of the if and else clauses, but not smart enough to know that the second if is always true (in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Use this to make every thing simple and short. but a little fat :)

```
string homeAdd = homeAddressText.Text == String.Empty ?  " " :  homeAddressText.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is to do:

```
string homeAdd = string.IsNullOrEmpty(homeAddressText.Text) ? " " : homeAddressText.Text;
```

for your initialization of `homeAdd`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second if condition.

Even though your conditions are mutually exclusive, the compiler doesn't look that far. Moreover, multi-threading issues could in theory cause the value of `homeAddressText.Value` to change. So, the compiler (correctly) assumes that there is a possibility that both conditions will return false, in which case `homeAdd` is indeed not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
string homeAdd = " ";
if (homeAddress.Text != String.Empty) {
    homeAdd = homeAddress.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
   string homeAdd = String.Empty;
    if (homeAddressText.Text != String.Empty)
    {
        homeAdd = homeAddressText.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code if you use else not else if, then your problem will be solved.

Here I am posting a demo code which I will do if I have this kind of problem.

```
using System;

namespace MyCompany
{
    internal class Client
    {
        // Class fields and properties.
        private string firstName;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set { SetStringValue(ref firstName, value); }
        }

        private string lastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set { SetStringValue(ref lastName, value); }
        }

        private string homeAddress;
        public string HomeAddress
        {
            get { return homeAddress; }
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    homeAddress = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    homeAddress = "No home address";
                }
            }
        }

        private string workAddress;
        public string WorkAddress
        {
            get { return workAddress; }
            set { SetStringValue(ref workAddress, value); }
        }

        private string email;
        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { SetStringValue(ref email, value); }
        }

        private long homePhone;
        public long HomePhone
        {
            get { return homePhone; }
            set { SetLongValue(ref homePhone, value); }
        }

        private long cellPhone;
        public long CellPhone
        {
            get { return cellPhone; }
            set { SetLongValue(ref cellPhone, value); }
        }

        // Constructors.
        public Client(string firstName, string lastName, string homeAddress, string workAddress,
            string email, long homePhone, long cellPhone)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
            this.HomeAddress = homeAddress;
            this.WorkAddress = workAddress;
            this.Email = email;
            this.HomePhone = homePhone;
            this.CellPhone = cellPhone;
        }

        // Supporting methods for initialization.
        private void SetStringValue(ref string field, string value)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                field = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            }
        }

        private void SetLongValue(ref long field, long value)
        {
            if (value != 0)
            {
                field = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }
    }

    internal class ClientDemo
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Inputs.
            Console.Write("Enter your first name: ");
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter your last name: ");
            string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter your home address: ");
            string homeAddress = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter your work address: ");
            string workAddress = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter your email: ");
            string email = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter your home phone: ");
            long homePhone = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter your cell phone: ");
            long cellPhone = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            // Create client object, assuming that without home address all the fields have data.
            Client myClient = null;
            try
            {
                myClient = new Client
                    (firstName, lastName, homeAddress, workAddress, email, homePhone, cellPhone);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            // Show result.
            Console.WriteLine();

            if (myClient != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myClient.FirstName);
                Console.WriteLine(myClient.LastName);
                Console.WriteLine(myClient.HomeAddress);
                Console.WriteLine(myClient.WorkAddress);
                Console.WriteLine(myClient.Email);
                Console.WriteLine(myClient.HomePhone);
                Console.WriteLine(myClient.CellPhone);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.
Thanks.